# How to get updated value from vuex store in component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

I want to show a progress bar in a component. The value of the progress bar should be set by the value of `onUploadProgress` in the post request (axios). Till so far, that works well. The state is updated with that value correctly.
Now, I am trying to access that value in the component. As the value updates while sending the request, I tried using a `watch`, but that didn't work.

**So, the question is, how to get that updated value in a component?**

What I tried:

*component.vue*

```js
    computed: {
      uploadProgress: function () {
        return this.$store.state.content.object.uploadProgressStatus;
      }
    }
    watch: {
      uploadProgress: function(newVal, oldVal) { // watch it
        console.log('Value changed: ', newVal, ' | was: ', oldVal)
      }
    }
```

*content.js*

```js
    // actions
    const actions = {
      editContentBlock({ commit }, contentObject) {
        commit("editor/setLoading", true, { root: true });
        let id = object instanceof FormData ? contentObject.get("id") : contentObject.id;
        return Api()
          .patch(`/contentblocks/${id}/patch/`, contentObject, {
            onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
              commit("setOnUploadProgress", parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100)));
            },
          })
          .then((response) => {
            commit("setContentBlock", response.data.contentblock);
            return response;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
          });
      },
    };
    // mutations
    const mutations = {
      setOnUploadProgress(state, uploadProgress) {
        return (state.object.uploadProgressStatus = uploadProgress);
      },
    };
```

Setup:

- Vue 2.x
- Vuex
- Axios

Comment: Can you show the state and the code that updates state when progress changes?

Comment: @Dan I added the code. Updating the state works. Retrieving that value in the component is where I am stuck.

Comment: What is `content`? Is it the module name of your store?

Comment: @UtsavPatel yes that's the module name of the store.

Comment: So what do you get when you try to access it?
Also are you able to access `this.$store.state.content` ?

Comment: @UtsavPatel Yes I can, though, that state is set by another API call of which `uploadProgressStatus` is not a property. That property is added through the mutation in code above.

Comment: @Vincent I am confused. 
You should have a property named `uploadProgressStatus` and only update its value through mutation.
Are you adding that property in mutation?
Does not look like so

Comment: @UtsavPatel thank you for your time. As soon as I explained how I was adding that property I felt that was the problem. I add the property in the other API call to set that `content` state and it works.

Comment: Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

`Mutations` generally are not meant to have a return value, they are just to purely there set a state value, Only `getters` are expected to return a value and dispatched actions return either `void` or a `Promise`.

When you `dispatch` an `action`, a `dispatch` returns a `promise` by default and in turn an `action` is typically used to call an endpoint that in turn on success `commits` a response value via a `mutation` and finally use a `getter` to get the value or map the `state` directly with [mapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper).

If you write a `getter` (not often required) then [mapGetters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper) is also handy to make vuex getters available directly as a computed property.

> Dispatch > action > commit > mutation > get

Most of your setup appears correct so it should be just a case of resolving some `reactivity` issue:

```js
// content.js

const state = {

  uploadProgress: 0

}

const actions = {

  editContentBlock (context, contentObject) {

    // other code

    .patch(`/contentblocks/${id}/patch/`, contentObject, {

      onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {

        context.commit('SET_UPLOAD_PROGRESS', 
          parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100)));

      },
    }

    // other code

  }

}

const mutations = {

  SET_UPLOAD_PROGRESS(state, uploadProgress) {

    state.uploadProgress = uploadProgress

  }

}
```

```js
// component.vue

<template>

  <div> {{ uploadProgress }} </div>

</template>

<script>

import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {

  computed: {

    ...mapState('content', ['uploadProgress']) // <-- 3 dots are required here.

  }

}

</script>
```